# Storing user defined configuration settings to be used by another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my current web app, I want to allow users to modify some settings of the settings for some natural language parsing.

However I'm confused about how to pass these settings around - the user will go from the home page to the settings page and on submission of the form the user is taken back to the home page where they can search happily.

The relevant code is:

```
 public ActionResult Settings(Configuration configuration)
   {
        TempData["configStructure"] = configurationStructure;
        return RedirectToAction("ConfigSet", "Home", configuration);
   }
```

And in the home controller:

```
public ActionResult ConfigSet(Configuration configuration)
{            
    return View("Index");
}
```

I'm generating a partial view with:

```
public PartialViewResult Search(string q)
{
    List<Stuff> results = this.Search(q);
    return PartialView("SearchResults", results);
}
```

With the partial view rendered like so:

```
@model MyApp.MySettings.ConfigurationApi

@if (Model == null)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "searchResults",
    }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
}
else
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new { configuration = Model }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "searchResults",
     }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="configuration" />
        <input type="text" name="searchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
}
```

Basically I'm confused about how I'd go about passing these values from the settings page to the home page and tie the settings to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users are authenticated, and if you want your user to have the settings the next time they hit your web site, you should consider Asp.Net Membership Profiles.  You could also elect to store the settings in the database.

You have the option of storing the object in a Session variable, but that makes some people angry.

You also have the option of storing the settings in the ViewBag before redirecting the user to  Home.Index.  You can do this by setting `ViewBag.Settings = configuration` before returning the view. Then you could access the settings in `@ViewBag.Settings` from within your view. Note that this method is lossy...as in, go to a different page and you've lost your settings.

For unauthenticated users, the session might be the way to go.